# Welcome Message Python Discord Bot

Tags: python, discord, bots, message

I want to make a Discord Bot with Python3.
I want to add a message in the `#welcome` Channel and a message via `PM` to the new user.
I get no error but the bot doesn't sent any messages.

Here is my code:

```
#welcome message
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='willkommen')
    await channel.send(f"Hallo auf dem Server")
    await message.author.send(f"Hallo auf dem Server")
```

Here are the imports:

```
import discord
import random
import asyncio
import logging
from discord.ext import commands
```

Someone have an idea How I can fix this?
Thanks!! :)

Comment: Replace `message.author` with `member.send(...)` and `utils.get` can return `None` if the channel is not found so check before you send the message.

Comment: Furthermore, discord.py has a entire framework build around making a Bot which includes commands, cogs, checks, and lots of cool stuff which you should look at.

Comment: I had looked at the Framework but there only were the command 
`async def on_member_join(member):`

No I have replace message.author with member.send but it not works and the Channel is correct and the bot have permissions to write a message in the welcome Channel